Mac: LaTeX (BasicTex) in VSCode not finding tablefootnote.sty
I've read a number of similar issues on here, which were helpful in giving new things to look for/try, but I'm still having no luck.
What I've done:

downloaded BasicTex for Mac (OS 14.4), used wizard to install

updated .bash_profile and confirmed tlmgr is a recognized command

followed the steps described by gsalgueiros here to install necessary packages (all but synctext installed for me, that one gave the error "package synctext not present in repository")

added the LaTex Workshop and LaTeX Utilities extensions to VSCode

updated the LaTeX extension settings to set the paths to the installed packages (I could only find a few places in the Settings that asked for these, unsure about this)

restarted VSCode

tried to build my .tex file and got a warning about chktex not being found, but after some Googling it looks like I can ignore that one

I also get an error that fails the build: File "tablefootnote.sty not found"

confirmed the style files are in /usr/local/texlive/2024basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdwtools, including tablefootnote.sty

ran tlmgr info mdwtools and get
package:     mdwtools
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Miscellaneous tools by Mark Wooding
longdesc:    This collection of tools includes: support for short commands starting with @, macros to sanitise the OT1 encoding of the cmtt fonts; a 'do after' command; improved footnote support; mathenv for various alignment in maths; list handling; mdwmath which adds some minor changes to LaTeX maths; a rewrite of LaTeX's tabular and array environments; verbatim handling; and syntax diagrams.
installed:   Yes
revision:    15878
sizes:       run: 125k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.05.4
cat-license: gpl
cat-topics:  list-supp notes footnote syntax maths macro-supp table verbatim
collection:  collection-latexrecommended

ran kpsewhich footnote.sty and get "./footnote.sty"

tried updating permissions with sudo chown -R [username] /usr/local/texlive and restarting VSCode again


Update: I just realized the found style file is footnote.sty and not tablefootnote.sty. Ugh. Ok, I grabbed tablefootnote from here and followed the README to install. Unfortunately, after adding "tablefootnote.sty" to /usr/local/texlive/2024basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tablefootnote, VSCode and pdflatex still both say they cannot find it.

welcome! why did you do kpsewhich footnote.sty if you need tablefootnote.sty? why not kpsewhich tablefootnote.sty. changing the ownership of /usr/local/texlive arbitrarily is not a great idea. not on Macs, anyway. are you really short of disk space that you need to endure the misery of installing BasicTeX rather than a full MacTeX?

you are missing tablefootnote.sty so it isn't clear why you discuss mdwtools or footnote.sty or vscode, you are missing /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tablefootnote/tablefootnote.sty  so tlmgr install tablefootnote

@DavidCarlisle For the Mac you need to use sudo tlmgr ... to install packages. Or use the included TeXLive Utility GUI.

@AlanMunn not if you've just chowned it to your user?

@cfr I guess, but that's not the default.

@AlanMunn sure yes usually on linux as well, my main point was to install the missing package, not something else unrelated.

Ah, sorry, just refreshed the page and seeing these comments now. @cfr yes, I just caught that it was my mistake thinking I had the tablefootnote.sty originally. I should have it now though! "...are you really short of disk space that you need to endure the misery of installing BasicTeX rather than a full MacTeX?" No! It just sounded like a good first step, like MiniConda instead of Anaconda. If it's not worth the effort, I'll uninstall and restart with MacTex!

@DavidCarlisle my mistake, thank you for pointing that out. I'm just jumping back into using LaTeX after about a decade away, so this is all reeeaally rusty for me (and has changed quite a bit!).

texlive does not auto-install anything so if you start with basictex the issue you ask about here is the expected result: packages are missing and you'll need to install them one by one until you have enough for your documents. It can save some space (especially if you never need Chinese fonts etc) but it does not save time or work.

Based on the comments and recommendations, I'm going to scratch this attempt and uninstall BasicTeX. I'll start again with MacTeX and go from there. Thanks to all who responded! Update: FWIW, after installing MacTeX my PDF built immediately and without issue -- both in and out of VSCode. Again, thanks for the help (and patience with newbies like me).
